# How to find the lower and upper bound of a solution of a Cauchy problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I am studying some differential equations especially the Cauchy problems, and I encountered this question:
\begin{equation}
(E):\bigg\{\begin{split}
y'=ysin^{2}(y)\\
y(0)=x_{0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
They supposed that $0<x_{0}<\pi$, and I have to find the upper and lower bounds of the solution, knowing that it is a maximal solution.
I don't know where to start. I need some kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $f(y)=y\sin^2(y)$ you know that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ with $f(y)>0$ inside that interval, and that this function is locally Lipschitz.

This is all you need to know to solve this task.

Comment: So I am going to use the unicity of the maximal solution to this problem. Thanks!